# Not able to retrieve Notes(ContentNote Object) in Account

Tags: contentnote

When i tried to pull "ContentNote" i was getting the below exception.

INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'ContentNote' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Then i tried with 'ContentNote__c' i was getting the same exception.

INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'ContentNote__c' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Could you anyone help me how to pull ContentNote data?

Comment: Just had same error and changing the API version of the class containing the query to 32.0 fixed it for me,.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to enable the new notes feature as mentioned in following help document, if not done already:

- [Considerations for enabling the enhanced note-taking tool (Notes) and using Files](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Consideration-for-enhanced-notes-and-using-Files&type=1)

Other cause could be that your API version of class/trigger to a lower version than 32.0.

From [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentnote.htm):

> ContentNote: Represents a note in Salesforce. This object is available
>   in API version 32.0 and later.

Comment: I have checked in Note Settings and its already enabled!.

Comment: Just had same error and changing the API version of the class containing the query to 32.0 fixed it for me,